# How to download magento

Tags: magento-community, installation, download

I want to download the Magento Community Edition from this page

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

In the Full Release section I choose the zip version and click "Download".

It's open a window where I can login / register. I already have a user, so i'm logging in using my email and password and i'm redirected to "My Account" section.

On I once again click in the nav bar on Products -> Open Source / CE -> View available download -> choose zip version -> click "Download", it's opening again the login/register window.

I'm in loop... How can I download the Magento Community Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just direct him to the Download link for the ZIP version (Which is the one he's after)

Go to http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.zip
in your browser. .... Dahhhh

Comment: looks like right now the only way is to download magento to your pc from download page, no direct links anymore, or svn `svn -q checkout http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9  .` and then latest patches....

Comment: For two reasons: 1) Magento 1.9.0.1 won't be the latest version forever. 2) the deeplinks might change over time. Both is the case now and your answer basically worthless.

Answer (score 17):

For the ones who didn't see the system:

Magento Version 1.x.y.z can be downloaded from

http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.x.y.z/magento-1.x.y.z.zip

Works for Version smaller (not including) 1.9.2.0
The "problem" with versions 1.9.2.0+ is, that magento makes silent updates - changing code without changing the version number. But thankfully, they add the timestamp to the file now. So this system doesn't work anymore, but we now know the REAL version we download.

Thanks https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9bc45ec84028611d621e

> 1) First you need to generate download token. Login to your account on
>   magento.com and generate it in Account Settings->Downloads Access
>   Token
>
> 2) You will need your MAGEID as well. It is shown at the
>   top-left in your account page.
>
> 3) `curl -k https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/help`
>
> 4) Profit!

Comment: It won't work for 1.9.2.z.

Comment: Correct. Added a paragraph about this "problem"

Comment: updated again with a new cool way to do it

Comment: At the moment, neither the direct download links nor the cool new way works (always shows "no results found"). But the latter is at least supposed to work, while the links are probably gone forever.

Answer (score 11):

Wondering why nobody mentioned https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to re-create a login loop. It's likely you have a cookie or cache problem causing this issue.

However, you should be able to download the latest CE version of Magento via ssh or your local shell by running the following:

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz
```

More info here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

(or you can just point your browser to http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz ;)

Well, since mage doesn't have a generic latest.tar.gz link - the current latest is now http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.1.1/magento-1.9.1.1.tar.gz - hopefully they remedy the link situation w/ M2

Comment: The linked documentation is outdated and the download links mentioned there and in your answer don't work anymore.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler I can't be bothered to update them since Magento doesn't seem to have a link preservation policy and I no longer Magento, but feel free to edit the answer with the proper links....

Answer (score 2):

In case you try to download the latest 1.x version nowadays, to get the latest version you can go to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download click on 'Release Archive' and look for '**Downloader - 1.x**' (waay down, bottom half of the page).

DON'T do what i did and go looking for a specific 1.x version number like 1.9.3.9 or sth. because you WON'T find that on the official page.

There is a downloader that will automagically download the latest 1.x version for you, thats what you have to get, the DOWNLOADER.

If you want a SPECIFIC 1.x version, go to https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror, as the name says they are a mirror for the Magento 1.x releases.

**TL;DR**

You can't download specific 1.x versions from the Magento.com page anymore, for the latest version get the 'Downloader 1.x' from the oficial page [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download), or go to [OpenMage](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror) which is an unoficial mirror for all 1.x releases.

**2021 SOLUTION:**

As the development of Magento 1 has stopped (in June 2020) there will be no more updates for it from Adobe.

The good new is that there is a great fork by OpenMage though which is being developed by the  community. It is called [Magento LTS](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts).

It is completely backwards compatible to the latest Magento 1 version.

Answer (score 1):

To download all magento 2 releases one can follow :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 0):

Security patches can be found in Magento patches mirror repository – https://github.com/akai-z/magento1-open-source-patches