# Can't download sample data from ssh anymore

Tags: sample-data, deployment

I've always downloaded sample data from this link:

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.1.0/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.gz

But today I got 404.

I've read this answer (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58031/4276) from Fabian Blechschmidt, which explains how you can download whatever you want with MAGEID and Download Access Token. But sample data was not included.

If you run:

> curl
>   https://MAGEID:ACCESS_TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/files

You'll get:

[image]

So where can I download sample data over ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Magento forgot about sample data 1.x and only supports 2.0 for time being. meanwhile you can use one of unofficial mirrors like this:

http://mirror.gunah.eu/magento/sample-data/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.gz