# Not able to download Magento

Tags: download

I'm newbie in Magento and as a newbie my first question is how to download magento. I tried it from the [official website](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) but it does not get downloaded. I want to download latest version of Magento with and without sample data to learn. I created the account and when I press the download button it takes too much time and throws error.Is there anything I'm missing to download from the official website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28582/how-to-download-magento)

Comment: @Sanjok Can you update your question with the error screenshot?

Comment: If you want to develop a Magento 2 site, the recommended installation is using composer, not direct download. But for a quick start, there is also the "hosted installation" type. Please follow these steps and come back if you have a concrete error: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/hosted/hosted_start.html

Comment: @MagenX I disagree, this old question only has answers for Magento 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download it with the link you mentioned

[Download Page Magento.com](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download)

That should be it, I just tried with my account and it also didn´t work. Might just be in issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it with both, with and w/o sample data. Both links are working fine for tar.gz and zip version.

Are you sure, you're logged in? Maybe any adblocker oder Popup Blocker or things like no-script are blocking on your side?

Answer (score 0):

To get your authentication keys: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html#auth-get

CREATE WEB USER AND DEPLOY MAGENTO 2 INTO `/home/username/public_html`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "|                               DOWNLOADING MAGENTO                                 |"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo
echo
     MAGENTO_VER=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2/releases 2>&1 | head -12 | grep 'tag_name' | grep -oP '(?<=")\d.*(?=")')
     REPO_MAGENTO="composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition"
     echo
     read -e -p "---> Enter your domain name (without www.): " -i "myshop.com" MY_DOMAIN
     MY_SHOP_PATH="/home/${MY_DOMAIN%%.*}/public_html"
     echo
        echo "  Magento ${MAGENTO_VER} will be downloaded to:"
        echo ${MY_SHOP_PATH}
        mkdir -p ${MY_SHOP_PATH} && cd $_
        useradd -d ${MY_SHOP_PATH%/*} -s /sbin/nologin ${MY_DOMAIN%%.*}  >/dev/null 2>&1
        LINUX_USER_PASS=$(head -c 500 /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 15 | head -n 1)
        echo "${MY_DOMAIN%%.*}:${LINUX_USER_PASS}"  | chpasswd  >/dev/null 2>&1
        chown -R ${MY_DOMAIN%%.*}:${MY_DOMAIN%%.*} ${MY_SHOP_PATH%/*}
        echo
        curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php >/dev/null 2>&1
        mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
        echo
        echo
        su ${MY_DOMAIN%%.*} -s /bin/bash -c "${REPO_MAGENTO} ."
        echo
     echo
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "|                   MAGENTO DOWNLOADED AND READY FOR INSTALLATION                   |"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

.

**provided you have all webstack installed and configured.**

.