# Where can I find the last Magento 1.9.3.x package?

Tags: magento-1, download, magento-1.9.3.8

If I look [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) I can find only a 1.9.2 version.
I'd like to upgrade on a new fresh installation, but I can't find a recent full Magento version...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9bc45ec84028611d621e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58031/31999)

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Release Archive" panel - It is right to the "Download" under "For Magento Open Source 2.x and 1.x"

Scroll down and scroll down to Magento 1 or just search by '1.9.3.8'

And there you are ;)

Comment: i swear i did what you said, but and i only found the patch. Now i find it! So, sorry for my stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

There are two teams who are managing Magento 1.x releases.

Below are the links for downloading the latest Magento 1.9.3.8.

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.3.8.zip

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/archive/1.9.3.8.zip

Comment: why did you downvoted?